# How can I refresh a folder with Java code?

Tags: java, maven, testing, automated-tests, cucumber

**What I am trying to do:**

Generate a test report after the test execution is done and then email it( I am using Maven, cucumber and RestAssured).

**The issue that I am facing:**

Everything from the above mentioned is happening, except the test report which gets e-mailed is actually from previous test execution. That is, the report or the folder that has the report, is not getting refreshed when the code to email the report runs.

Is there any way to refresh the folder at the end of the test execution through maven or is there any other way with which I can send the latest test report..?

Any pointer is much appreciated. Below is my Cucumber runner code,

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/resources/Feature"
    ,glue= "com/sss/tests/RestApi"
    ,tags = {"@TestInDevelopment"}
    ,plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:/Report.html"}        
    ,format = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber"}
    ,monochrome = true
    )

public class TestRunner { 
static Configurations config = new Configurations();

@BeforeClass
public static void setup(){

    /*
     * Loading the log4j configurations, before the start of test execution
     */     
    String folderName = "PropertyFiles";
    String fileName = "log4j.properties";
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(config.getResourcePath(folderName)+fileName);

}

@AfterClass
public static void teardown() throws UnknownHostException, IOException, InterruptedException {

    /*
     * Loading the configuration file for the test execution report and setting up the user name, OS info and host details in the report
     */     
    Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File(config.getResourcePath("Resources")+"extent-config.xml"));
    Reporter.setSystemInfo("USER", System.getProperty("user.name"));
    Reporter.setSystemInfo("OS", System.getProperty("os.name"));
    Reporter.setSystemInfo("HOST NAME", InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());  

   /*
    * After the test execution is completed, parsing the generated test execution report to to see if there is any failures and based on that,
    * sending the Build Success/Failure e-mail to the configured mail list
    */        
    HTML_TestExecutionReportParser testExecutionStatusParser = new HTML_TestExecutionReportParser();    
    TestExecutionReportEmailSender testExecutionReportMailSender = new TestExecutionReportEmailSender();        
    testExecutionReportMailSender.sendTestExecutionReportEmail(testExecutionStatusParser.isAssertionFailureFound(), testExecutionStatusParser.errorsFoundList());     

}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure the report is written yet when `@AfterClass` is executed?

Comment: I deleted the old report and ran my tests, it threw FileNotFoundException. I was assuming the report is written during the execution of  `@AfterClass` and that still a refresh is needed on folder level. But if the report is written after `@AfterClass` is executed, I am just wondering where will I handle the emailing part, because  `@AfterClass` supposed to be the last code block that gets executed.

Comment: Try placing the emailing code inside a jvm shutdown hook. Maybe it works. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jvm-shutdown-hook-java/

Comment: Thank you @Grasshopper, placing the emailing code inside the shutdown hook worked for me and it is now sending the latest report instead of the old one. Although I am not sure if it is a good idea or practice, it does serve my need at the moment. I can up-vote if you could post this as your answer.

Comment: @Qaddaffi The only other solution is to go through the source code of the formatter to figure out when the flush() method is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with placing the emailing code inside a `JVM shutdown hook`. Thus it will be called when every other process is done.

Example of a shutdown hook -- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jvm-shutdown-hook-java/

Comment: Up-vote is again not allowed for me as my reputation is less than 15. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries... Nothing to be sorry about